# How fast is Redis compared to pure memory? Pros and cons of using Redis rather than pure memory

Tags: memory, redis

I am building a real-time application where the clients get the state of the app every second. I am considering using pure memory or Redis and I am not sure which one is faster. Most likely pure memory is faster but at what cost? What are the benefits of Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really an expert in this field but I assume

memory will be faster assuming you'd use proper structure (dict)

- redis can store data to the amount limited by your HDD space, while storing in memory is limited by free ram
- data stored in redis will not get lost eg in case of power outage, reboot etc.